# How to plot a CDF functon from PDF in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following function:

```
fx <- function(x) {
  if(x >= 0 && x < 3) {
    res <-  0.2;
  } else if(x >=3 && x < 5) {
    res <- 0.05;
  } else if(x >= 5 && x < 6) {
    res <-  0.15;
  } else if(x >= 7 && x < 10) {
    res <-  0.05;
  } else {
    res <- 0;
  }

  return(res);
}
```

How can I plot it's [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) function on the interval `[0,10]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a bit accuracy to @Martin Schmelzer's answer. A *cummulative distribution function(CDF)*

> evaluated at x, is the probability that X will take a value less than
>   or equal to x

So to get CDF from *Probability Density Function(PDF)*, you need to integrate on PDF:

```
fx <- Vectorize(fx)
dx <- 0.01
x <- seq(0, 10, by = dx)
plot(x, cumsum(fx(x) * dx), type = "l", ylab = "cummulative probability", main = "My CDF")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. It's too late for me. Time to go to bed :)

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Sure. No worries.

Comment: It's actually not a single value, since we vectorized `fx`, it takes a vector `x` and returns another vector. You can see this more clearly after you run `Vectorize(fx)(x)` where `x <- seq(0, 10, by = 0.01)`

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
fx   <- Vectorize(fx)
grid <- 0:10
p    <- fx(grid)
cdf  <- cumsum(p)

plot(grid, cdf, type = 'p', ylim = c(0, 1), col = 'steelblue',
     xlab = 'x', ylab = expression(F(x)), pch = 19, las = 1)
segments(x0 = grid, x1 = grid + 1, y0 = cdf)
segments(x0 = grid + 1, y0 = c(cdf[-1], 1), y1 = cdf, lty = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just adding up on the previous answers and using ggplot

```
# cdf
Fx <- function(x, dx) {
  cumsum(fx(x)*dx)
}

fx <- Vectorize(fx)
dx <- 0.01
x <- seq(0, 10, dx)
df <- rbind(data.frame(x, value=fx(x), func='pdf'), 
            data.frame(x, value=Fx(x, dx), func='cdf'))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, value, col=func)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + ylim(0, 1)
```

[image]