# Is there an R function to compute the cumulative distribution function?

Tags: r

I want to plot a power function of the form B = Phi(-1.96 + 35.7*x) versus x. Where Phi denotes the cumulative distribution function and where x is between 0 and 0.4.
I tried the code below but it doesn't return the expected plot.

```
x = seq(0,0.5,by=0.01)
ggplot(data.frame(x=x, cumulative=pnorm(-1.96 + sqrt(0.5*50*51)*x,0,1)), aes(x,cumulative))+geom_line()+ggtitle('Power')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot a CDF functon from PDF in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317876/how-to-plot-a-cdf-functon-from-pdf-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
#Function
Phi <- function(x){-1.96 + 35.7*x}
x <- seq(0,0.3,by=0.01)
Phi <- Vectorize(Phi)
dx <- 0.01
plot(x, cumsum(Phi(x) * dx), type = "l", ylab = "cummulative probability", main = "My CDF")
```

Output:

[image]